# Como descobrir o signo zodiaco através da data de nascimento utilizando javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar uma função que obtém a data de nascimento e retorna o signo. O código que estou tentando é o seguinte:

```js
var dateString = "19/08/1989"
var dateParts = dateString.split("/");
var dateObject = new Date(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] -1, +dateParts[0]);
const date = dateObject;
```

Nesse ponto eu já consigo colocar a data no formato internacional, mas não sei como obter o signo. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Aqui um exemplo de código que eu utilizo sempre que preciso desenvolver algo que necessite desse tipo de solução:

```js
var dateString = "19/08/1989";
// armazene a data de nascimento na variável dateString.

const [day, month, year] = dateString.split("/").map(Number);
// divida a data de nascimento em um array de três valores (dia, mês e ano) usando o método split() com o separador "/". Em seguida, cada valor é convertido em número usando o método map() com a função Number(). Esses valores são atribuídos às variáveis day, month e year usando a sintaxe de desestruturação de array.

const dateObject = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
// Crie um objeto de data usando o construtor Date(), que recebe três argumentos: o ano, o mês (que começa em 0 para janeiro) e o dia. A variável dateObject armazena o objeto de data criado.

const findSign = (date) => {
  // Defina a função findSign(), que recebe um objeto de data como argumento.
  const days = [21, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 24, 24, 23, 22];
  // A matriz days contém o dia em que o signo do zodíaco muda para cada mês do ano.
  const signs = [
    "Aquário", "Peixes", "Áries", "Touro", "Gêmeos", "Câncer",
    "Leão", "Virgem", "Libra", "Escorpião", "Sagitário", "Capricórnio"
  ];
  // A matriz signs contém os nomes dos signos do zodíaco.

  let month = date.getMonth();
  let day = date.getDate();
  // As variáveis month e day são inicializadas com o mês e o dia do objeto de data recebido como argumento.

  if (day < days[month]) {
    month--;
  }
  // Se o dia da data for menor do que o dia do signo em que o mês atual começa, o mês é reduzido em 1 para que o signo correspondente ao mês anterior seja retornado.

  if (month < 0) {
    month = 11;
  }
  // Se o mês for menor que 0 (isto é, se o mês for dezembro e o signo correspondente estiver em janeiro), o índice do mês é ajustado para 11 (janeiro).

  return signs[month];
  // A função retorna o signo correspondente ao mês.
};
const sign = findSign(dateObject);
console.log(sign);
```

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado.